# meta_query 'compare' => '!=' not working

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I am using a custom post-type, in post there are a checkbox meta field for **featured post**.

So there are two scenarios.

1. First with featured posts
2. Second with non featured

When I called featured posts with `meta_query` its result 100% perfect.

Here is my code:

```
$c_clients_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'clients_testimonials',
                    'posts_per_page' => 6,
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'c_client_feature',
                                            'value' => 'on'
                                        )
                                    )
                );

$c_clients_result = new WP_Query($c_clients_args);

if($c_clients_result->have_posts()) :
    while($c_clients_result->have_posts()) :
         $c_clients_result->the_post();

         // My result
    endwhile;
endif;
```

But when I call non featured posts with `meta_query` the Page goes blank.

Here is my code:

```
$c_client_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'clients_testimonials',
                    'posts_per_page' => 999,
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'c_client_feature',
                                            'value' => 'on',
                                            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
                                        )
                                    )
                );
```

I also tried `!=` and `NOT IN`

So please guide me.

Comment: and if you use 10 instead of 999? why do you think it has anything to do with the query at all?

Comment: I want infinite data of non featured post

Comment: and nothing happen when i convert 999 to 10

Comment: There is not "infinite" data in WordPress, but if you want to get all posts that match the query, use `nopaging => true` and `posts_per_page => -1`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Are you sure that `c_client_feature` meta field exists for non featured posts?

Comment: ok, time to actually define "nothing happens" and "blank", and what do you see in the error logs

Comment: @cybmeta `c_client_feature` exist with every post but I assign post as feature its value is on and when I don't assign it the value goes empty

Comment: maybe test `NOT EQUALS` ?

Comment: Empty implies that the entry exists in database, but with value equal to `""` (emtpy string), is it or the entry in database doesn't exist?

Comment: entry exist in database. as empty string like you said ""

Answer (score 1):

Issue with your second query for non-featured posts is that `'NOT LIKE'` and `'!='` comparisons might not be working as expected for a checkbox field. For checkbox fields in WordPress, you should generally use `'NOT EXISTS'` or `'!= 1'` in the meta_query

try this second query

```
$c_client_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'clients_testimonials',
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'c_client_feature',
            'value'   => 'on',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', // Use 'NOT EXISTS' for checkbox fields
        ),
    ),
);

$c_client_result = new WP_Query($c_client_args);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this second query

```
  $c_client_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'clients_testimonials',
                    'posts_per_page' => 999,
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'meta_query'  => array(
                         'relation' => 'OR',
                          array(
                             'key' => 'c_client_feature',
                             'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' 
                          ),
                          array(
                             'key' => 'c_client_feature',
                             'value' => 'on',
                             'compare' => 'NOT IN' 
                          ),
                        )
                );
```

Comment: noting happend bro :(

Comment: use wp_reset_query(); after end of loop

Comment: comment all code your first query which is working and check second is working ? means remove first query for testing purpose